# Is possible join paths in one query of AWS Athena?

Tags: join, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Be studying use Athena in my project, but i dont't found possiblity of join folders in one request of Athena.

Example
i have datalog in folders day1 and day2, and i my query i need get data of both folders. In unique query! it's possible?

Comment: what is missing in a Join query?

Answer (score 0):

A table in Amazon Athena points to one folder in Amazon S3.

Therefore, you could:

- Create a table for `day1`
- Create a table for `day2`
- `CREATE VIEW days AS SELECT * FROM day1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM day2`
- `SELECT col1, col2 FROM days`

The View will act as the combined table for `day1` and `day2`.

Comment: Good idea! I go try this here.
I read the pricing of Athena, and the high monetary cost for
data processing made me worried, this service is a good idea for APIs? without pay one micro fortune.

Comment: Amazon Athena can be excellent value compared to traditional databases that incur charges even when they aren't being actively used. You only pay for the amount of data that Athena reads from disk, so you can reduce costs by storing compressed data (Zip files), using columnar data stores (eg Parquet / ORC files) and partitioning data into separate folders. See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)